# How to convert json output to Line format

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, influxdb-python

I am trying to send some custom metrics(outputs a json) to InfluxDB, are there any plugins or sample scripts that I can use to convert to Line protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-line-protocol .
You didn't mention about language you want to use to achieve this task so I propose using Node.js with above package that can be easily installed via NPM

@edit
Oh now I saw the tag python ... sorry :)
Anyway, as I see it's also easy to find sth for python
Did you check https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python ?